# Delete "on delete cascade" constraint

Tags: postgresql

In a previous command, I foolishly wrote:

```
alter table UserInfo
add column gcal_id integer references GoogleCal on delete cascade
```

I've since realized that I don't want `on delete cascade`. How do I alter `gcal-id` in `UserInfo` to no longer have that constraint without losing the information saved in current entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happily, it's fairly simple.

First `\d+ UserInfo` to see the constraint name, which will appear below the table's column definitions.

In your case it will probably be something like

```
Foreign-key constraints:
    "userinfo_gcal_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gcal_id) REFERENCES googlecal(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then, just drop and re-add the constraint in one command:

```
ALTER TABLE UserInfo
    DROP CONSTRAINT userinfo_gcal_id_fkey,
    ADD CONSTRAINT userinfo_gcal_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (gcal_id) REFERENCES googlecal(id);
```

omitting the `ON DELETE CASCADE` part.